# how can i change the Dimension from Pixels to any other like cm,millimeter etc

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry('361mx203m')
a = Label(root,text="hello everyone",font=('Helvetica',"25m"),anchor='center')
a.place(x=0,y=0)
b1 = Button(root,text="pal entry",height="100m",width="25m")
b1.place(x=10,y=50)


root.mainloop()
```

> TclError: expected integer but got "25m".

Suggest me a code to convert this into millimeters

Comment: The correct solution here is to forget that the `.place` geometry manager exists and use one of the useful geometry managers instead (`.pack` or `.grid`). Just a few days ago we had someone post his GUI where every widget was placed manually, and it looked absolutely horrible on my PC.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: that is completely unrelated to the question that was asked. It's good advice, but it has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 2):

Normally the `height` attribute for a `Button` is in the number of lines of text, not pixels. In order for it to be interpreted as pixels, the button must have an image.

From the canonical tcl/tk documentation for the button:

> *height* - Specifies a desired height for the button. If an image or bitmap is being displayed in the button then the value is in screen units (i.e. any of the forms acceptable to Tk_GetPixels); for text it is in lines of text. If this option is not specified, the button's desired height is computed from the size of the image or bitmap or text being displayed in it.

If you are using images, then you can use physical dimensions with a suffix. Without a suffix the value is interpreted as pixels. For example, the following will create a button that is one inch square:

```
empty_image=tk.PhotoImage(width=0, height=0)
f = tk.Button(root, image=empty_image, width='2.54c', height='1i')
```

These are the suffixes supported by tkinter:

- `c` - centimeters
- `i` - inches
- `m` - millimeters
- `p` - printers points (1/72 of an inch)

If you do not wish to use an image, you can use an invisible image along with your text to trigger the change in how the width and height are interpreted.

Note: you must remember to include the `compound` or the text will not show up.

For example:

```
empty_image = PhotoImage(width=0, height=0)
b1 = Button(root, image=empty_image, text="pal entry",
    compound="center", height="100m", width="25m")
```

Comment: @Muthuselvan I've updated my answer to show an example.

Comment: but i am using it in text..not for image

Comment: @Muthuselvan: I've updated my answer to include an example.

Comment: so ur conclusion is we cannot modify the dimensions to centimeters or millimeters????

Comment: @Muthuselvan: it's not a conclusion, it's the documented behavior. I've shown you how you can use centimeters, inches, millimeters, and printers points.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a string dimension to a number of pixels via:

```
widget.winfo_fpixels(str_dim)
```

According to https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm:

> winfo_fpixels(*distance*) [#]
>       Converts the given distance (in any form accepted by Tkinter) to the corresponding number of pixels.
>
> ```
> distance
>     The screen distance.
> Returns:
>     The corresponding number of screen pixels, as a floating point number.
> ```

As a quick test, I did:

```
b.winfo_fpixels('3m')
```

which gave the result `11.35180055401662`, and

```
b.winfo_fpixels('3')
```

which gave the result `3.0`

To go the other way, you'll have to do some math...

Since `b.winfo_fpixels('1m')` is 3.781388478581979, you can convert pixels to millimeters by dividing by that number.

So you could set `pix_per_1mm = b.winfo_fpixels('1m')`

Then, if you have 100 pixels, that would be 100 / pix_per_1mm = 26.4453125, which you could round to "26.4m"

You could similarly handle the other three dimensions (c, p, i), as well.